# React isn't returning the value from onClick

Tags: reactjs

```
export default class CreateMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  goToStage = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value < this.props.stage) {
      console.log('true')
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="campaign-pagination">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <span value={0} onClick={this.goToStage} className={this.props.menu.home} title="Info">
              <AlignLeft />
              <span className="navigation-text">1. Info</span>
            </span>
          </li>
```

Trying to access 'event.target.value' from a span with the value set as 0.  For some reason, it only returns null.

Comment: what value you're expecting should print?

Comment: I believe `span` element can't have `value` attribute according to spec. What is the desired behavior?